# How can I check whether all my threads are initiated and running at the background using python?

Tags: python, multithreading, initialization, multiprocessing

My objective is to create three threads using `Multithreading` and `Multiprocessing`. One thread is to read Modbus data, second one is to decode the data and third is to log the data into a file.

We started the thread and joined them. We are calling these threads in our main script. We are not getting any errors also output instead we doubt that our threads are not running. Can you please help us to identify the root cause of this and identify where it is stuck.

```
#Initializing threads
Thread_1=threading.Thread(target=Read.Read_Modbus,args=(MyEvents.Event,COMPORT,))
Thread_2=threading.Thread(target=Logging.Logging,args=(MyEvents.Event,Log_Name,LoggingQ,))  
Thread_3=threading.Thread(target=Decoding.decode(MyEvents.Event,DecodingQ,parameter_to_database,parameter_from_database,))
```

Comment: can you please show how you started your threads and how you join them?

Comment: We have used the below code to start and join threads,Specified random sleep time between each start                                                              `Thread_1.start()
sleep(2)
Thread_2.start()
sleep(5)
Thread_3.start()
sleep(2)
print("active threads count ", threading.active_count()) 
if(Stop_q.get()==1):
      MyEvents.Event.set()
        
#Wait for all the threads to join
Thread_1.join()
Thread_2.join()
Thread_3.join()`